# How do I determine which driver to install when vendor website lists dozens?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

*Background*

I serve as an IT guy for broader family, which means I get to install a new OS quite often but I don't have the luxury of standardized kit. I still prefer Windows 7 to alternatives, and a clean image from Microsoft as opposed to the preloaded image from vendor (if available, which is almost always not the case). I mainly work with Dell and HP laptops.

*The Problem*

Device manager full of unknown devices, Windows Update can't fund drivers. Vendor website lists multiple driver options for each device, often more than five for wireless adapter. Service tag or similar almost never helps to narrow the number of possibilities down.

Here is a (edited to reasonable size) a screenshot for HP 4330s. I figure some are just updates, though it is not 100% clear.

[image]

*The Question*

Is there a way to find out which one of all those drivers listed on the vendor support website I actually need?

Comment: What is the difference between the drivers? E.g. some models may have wifi of different brand, this case you'll have different drivers for them. Or some downloads may include additional tools too. I'm afraid it's not possible to give you a definite answer in general.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I added a snip from HP Support website for illustration - it lists at five different adapters for one model, when clearly there is only one  installed. What I ask about is whether there is a way to find out which one is installed in the particular computer.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite common that laptop manufacturers put different adapters in the same laptop model. In this case you need to know if the wireless adapter in your particular laptop came from Intel, Realtek, Atheros etc.

This information may or may not be found on a sticker under the laptop. Some manufacturers may have form on their website where you input a serial number and get the information you need. Or there's a mapping available somewhere, e.g. *Revision 1a* = Atheros, *Revision 1b* = Intel.

Opening the laptop and examining the adapter may also give a clue.

Or you can boot a live Linux distro and run `lspci`.

With this knowledge you still may have few download options left. Get the driver with highest (most recent) version number.

Comment: lspci is a very good idea! It didn't occur to me to look outside the windows world, what a shame :)